# Using a Power Pressure Cooker XL for high altitude canning above 6000 ft sea level

Tags: pressure-canner

I just purchased a Power Pressure Cooker XL and was planning on using it for canning. However, upon reading the owners manual, it says it is not recommended for canning over 2,000 ft sea level. I live at 6611 ft above sea level. Can I use this machine as long as I increase my cooking time by 5% per extra 1,000 feet above 2,000 ft? Or should I purchase something different to use for both home cooking & canning. Thank you.

Comment: I bought the same unit at Costco. I live at 2750 feet. I have an old fashioned one but was hoping for the ease of the Electric. I gave the electric one who lives at 600 feet. Big disappointment, but great score for her:)

Answer (score 3):

BEWARE that **no electric pressure cookers have been approved** for pressure canning by the USDA.  The National Center for Home Food Preservation actually [put out a bulletin](http://preservingfoodathome.com/2014/11/25/can-i-can-in-a-multi-cooker/) after manufacturers, like the Power Pressure Cooker XL, started to advertise that their cooker was USDA approved.

It is not.

Please do not pressure can in this, or any other electric pressure cooker.  See my pressure canning faq ([Can I use my electric pressure cooker to can?](http://www.hippressurecooking.com/pressure-canning-faq-put-em-up/#epc)) if you'd like to learn more about "*why*" pressure canning is not considered safe in electric pressure cookers - at any altitude.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by "power" you mean an electric pressure cooker/canner.  If so, increase the amount of pressure (in pounds) by 1/2 pound for every thousand feet above 2,000 feet.  Water bath canning requires that for foods that require 20 minutes or less processing time, you add 1 (one) additional minute for every 1,000 foot increment above 2,000 feet.  If the processing time is over 20 minutes then you add two minutes to every 1,000 feet above 2,000.